# Why result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() is not getting called?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

Currently i am implementing App indexing for android, `onCreate`,`onStart` and `onStop` methods are being called correctly but,
`result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>()` is not being called.
what can be the reason for this?

```
result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Status status) {
            Log.d("onresult","in On Result");
            if (status.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d(AppIndexingActivity.class.getName(), "App Indexing API Recorded page " + mTitle + " view end successfully.");
            }
            else {
                Log.e(AppIndexingActivity.class.getName(), "App Indexing API: There was an error recording the page view." + status.toString());
            }
        }
});
```

not reaching at onResults ..

Answer (score -1):

if the specified url path is correct then whenever that url specified page is viewed on success the page is recorded .

Comment: Can you please elaborate preferably with some code? I am also getting stuck here